# ¿Por qué no funcionan los estilos al imprimir en un bucle en PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, bucles

Ocurre algo muy curioso en mi código: intento imprimir parte de un contenido con color, pero no funciona. Es contenido con etiquetas HTML obtenido de una base de datos.

Este es mi código:

```
while ($row=$rows->fetch()){
    echo "<p style=\"color:red;\">$row[n]</p>$row[texto]";
}
```

Los valores de la columna `n`, o sea `852, 905, 1858` deberían imprimirse en rojo, pero no ocurre como pueden ver en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio, si pongo algo fuera del bucle sí se imprime en rojo, por ejemplo:

```
    echo "<p style=\"color:red;\">Lorem ipsum</p>";
```

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**¿Por qué no me asume el estilo en el código del bucle y cómo puedo hacer que funcione?**

Probé también con `<font color="red"> .... </font>` y nada.

##Código fuente

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<p style="color:red;">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p style="color:red;"></p>
852 
<p>
    <i>Los caminos de la misión</i>
    . "El Espíritu Santo es en verdad el protagonista de toda la misión eclesial" (
    <a href="http://w2.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/es/encyclicals/documents/hf_jp-ii_enc_07121990_redemptoris-missio.html">RM</a>
     21). Él es quien conduce la Iglesia por los caminos de la misión. Ella continúa y desarrolla en el curso de la historia la misión del propio Cristo, que fue enviado a evangelizar a los pobres; "impulsada por el Espíritu Santo, debe avanzar por el mismo camino por el que avanzó Cristo: esto es, el camino de la pobreza, la obediencia, el servicio y la inmolación de sí mismo hasta la muerte, de la que surgió victorioso por su resurrección" (
    <a href="http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decree_19651207_ad-gentes_sp.html">AG</a>
     5). Es así como la "sangre de los mártires es semilla de cristianos" (Tertuliano, 
    <i>Apologeticum</i>
    , 50, 13).
</p>
905 
<p>
    Los laicos cumplen también su misión profética evangelizando, con "el anuncio de Cristo comunicado con el testimonio de la vida y de la palabra". En los laicos, "esta evangelización [...] adquiere una nota específica y una eficacia particular por el hecho de que se realiza en las condiciones generales de nuestro mundo" (
    <a href="http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19641121_lumen-gentium_sp.html">LG</a>
     35):
</p>
<blockquote>
    <p>
        «Este apostolado no consiste sólo en el testimonio de vida; el verdadero apostolado busca ocasiones para anunciar a Cristo con su palabra, tanto a los no creyentes [...] como a los fieles» (
        <a href="http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decree_19651118_apostolicam-actuositatem_sp.html">AA</a>
         6; cf. 
        <a href="http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decree_19651207_ad-gentes_sp.html">AG</a>
         15).
    </p>
</blockquote>
1808 
<p>
    La 
    <i>fortaleza</i>
     es la virtud moral que asegura en las dificultades la firmeza y la constancia en la búsqueda del bien. Reafirma la resolución de resistir a las tentaciones y de superar los obstáculos en la vida moral. La virtud de la fortaleza hace capaz de vencer el temor, incluso a la muerte, y de hacer frente a las pruebas y a las persecuciones. Capacita para ir hasta la renuncia y el sacrificio de la propia vida por defender una causa justa. “Mi fuerza y mi cántico es el Señor” (
    <i>Sal</i>
     118, 14). “En el mundo tendréis tribulación. Pero ¡ánimo!: Yo he vencido al mundo” (
    <i>Jn</i>
     16, 33).
</p>
```

Comment: @Trauma he agregado al final un extracto del código fuente tal cual, copiado y pegado. Aparece un `<p style="color:red;"></p>` al principio del primer número, no entiendo por qué.

Comment: @Trauma no en el código: `echo "<p style=\"color:red;\">$row[n]</p>$row[texto]";`, sospecho que es un problema de agrupación de la consulta SQL, voy a revisar.

Comment: @Trauma era eso, un problema de agrupación, estaba usando `GROUP_CONCAT` y `CONCAT` en la instrucción SQL, por lo que el valor de `n` y de `texto` estaban viniendo en una sola columna. Ya lo he resuelto, gracias.

Comment: @BetaM era un problema de agrupación en la instrucción SQL.

Comment: Perfecto, esperamos nos puedas compartir la solución

Answer (score 1):

El problema no era el bucle en sí, sino mi instrucción SQL:

```
SELECT 
    ht.tema,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(hcj.n,' ',t.texto) separator '') AS texto
FROM ...
```

Realmente no existía una columna `n` independiente, por eso el código:

```
echo "<p style=\"color:red;\">$row[n]</p>$row[texto]";
```

imprimía esto en blanco: `<p style="color:red;"></p>` y luego el resto de contenido.

### Solución

En la instrucción SQL puse unos marcadores `%s` para aplicar el estilo:

```
SELECT 
    ht.tema,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('%s',hcj.n,'%s',t.texto) separator '') AS texto
FROM ...
```

Y en la lectura de los datos usé `printf()`:

```
while ($row=$rows->fetch()){
    printf("$row[texto]","<p style=\"color:red;\">","</p>");
}
```

Ahora funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]